# Running same task multiple times in parallel with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a Task that generates a PDF file for an order (it takes about 10 seconds to create one PDF):

```
public async Task GeneratePDF(Guid Id) {
   var order = await 
      _context
      .Orders
      .Include(order => order.Customer)
      ... //a lot more Include and ThenInclude statements
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(order ==> order.Id == Id);
   var document = ...  //PDF generated here, takes about 10 seconds
   order.PDF = document ;
   _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I tried the following:

```
public async Task GenerateAllPDFs() {
   var orderIds = await _context.Orders.Select(order=> order.Id).ToListAsync();
   foreach (var id in orderIds)
   {
      _ = GeneratePDF(id).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
   }
}
```

this gives me the error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

If I change the task as follows...

```
public async Task GenerateAllPDFs() {
   var orderIds = await _context.Orders.Select(order=> order.Id).ToListAsync();
   foreach (var id in orderIds)
   {
      _ = await GeneratePDF(id);
   }
}
```

...it runs the task for each order in series, taking ages to complete (I have a few thousands orders, taking about 10 seconds per order)...

How can I run this task in parallel for all orders in the context, so that the time it takes to complete is much less than sequential processing?

Comment: it looks for me as if `GeneratePDF` does too much. The part with the writing the stuff back to the server should not be in there. You need to separate it. 1) get all orders, 2) then do a `Parallel.Foreach` to generate all documents in parallel. and assign each document to the proper order and in the end 4) do a single ` _context.SaveChangesAsync();` to make a bulk update on the data on the server

Comment: this line: `var orderIds = await _context.Orders.Select(order=> order.Id).ToListAsync();` is actually superfluous. If you are querying the server, then you could already get all orders, since you need them anyway: `var allOrders = await _context.Orders.Select(order=> order).ToListAsync();`

Comment: @MongZhu that makes sense. let me try to refactor it.

Comment: @MongZhu Although your comment makes sense, it does not change the execution time.

Comment: did you measure the execution time of each step? which one takes the longest? did you change your code like I suggested in my answer? could you post it?

Comment: I am still refactoring it :)

Comment: What is the asp.net angle here? Because this is not what you should be doing inside a Web (API) request. Your first version runs afoul  of the scoped lifetime of the DbContext. Do not ignore the compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can map your order IDs to tasks and await them all like:

```
public async Task GeneratePDF(Order order) {
   var document = ...  //PDF generated here, takes about 10 seconds
   order.PDF = document ;
}

public async Task GenerateAllPDFs() {
   var orderIds = await _context.Orders.ToListAsync();
   var tasks = orderIds.Select((order) => GeneratePDF(order).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted));
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: this method works only partially, I get this error intermittently: ```System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.```

Comment: You have to move out your `context.SaveChangesAsync()` to the calling method. Let me update the code.

Comment: i have the feeling that this line: `var order = await _context.Orders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(order ==> order.Id == Id);` is actually causing the exception

Comment: If you don't need `GeneratePDF` to be reusable I'd follow what Mong Zhu mentioned in his answer. You'd reduce the roundtrips towards your DB, by pulling all required data at once.

Comment: Good one, big warning message about this on EF Cores docs.. :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async

Comment: @MongZhu Updated, though it's getting really similar to your answer.. :) If the generation of the PDF is async or need the generation to be reusable, you can use this answer, otherwise you're better off sticking with Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: @Grabofus, that is exactly what I struggle with now while trying to refactoring it based on Mong Zhu comment: this GeneratePDF has to be reusable, and has quite some complex logic in it (to retrieve references and collections of the Order)...

Comment: @intrixius than I suggest that you post more of this code

Comment: @MongZhu I just added some additional code to show why I am hesitating to fetch all the related properties in `GenerateAllPDFs`. If I would fetch all those related properties for all (thousands) of orders at once, wouldn't that get me in trouble memory wise?

Comment: @intrixius the generation of the document itself is still independent of all your db access code. Simply move this part into an extra method. and you can reuse it however you like

Comment: @intrixius "wouldn't that get me in trouble memory wise? " it might. But then you could just do it in batches of lets say 2000 or something. this will still give you an improvement on your velocity. The part that really troubles you is the document creation, which you try to parallelize. And we are actually focusing on that. both our answers takle this part.

Comment: You also won't be able to multi-thread on the same context as @MongZhu has mentioned previously. Ideally you read batches from your db and distribute the generation of PDFs across multiple threads.

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand what I should do. Is there any common practice to do the `GenerateAllPDFs` in batches?

Comment: I think you should do some more benchmarking so you know what parts of the code you have to worry about. (Like how much memory 2000 orders take in memory). You could make this more complicated and flexible by setting up a produces-consumer flow, so the code would be split to parts of batch-reading the data and filling it into a buffer for PDF generation. You could have X number of threads taking orders out of this buffer and processing the PDFs, then adding their results to a queue to batch insert it back into the database.

Comment: But I don't think you'll find something that you can just copy-paste into your code if you want it optimised for your exact requirements. :) Read this article, maybe you find something you can merge into your code: https://michaelscodingspot.com/performance-of-producer-consumer/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion from the comment as an answer. I would split it in 3 parts:

1) get all orders,

2) then do a Parallel.Foreach to generate all documents in parallel. and assign each document to the proper order and in the end

3) do a single `_context.SaveChangesAsync();` to make a bulk update on the data on the server

```
public async Task GenerateAllPDFs()
{
    var allOrders = await _context.Orders.ToListAsync();
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(allOrders, order => 
    {
        var document = ...  //PDF generated here, takes about 10 seconds
        order.PDF = document ;
    });
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: What's this part for? `.Select(order => order)`

Comment: @Grabofus you are right, I did not think that it access already the `Orders`. Thank you

Comment: Also (I know it's just copy paste of the original), but you should await the `SaveChangesAsync()` :)

Comment: @Grabofus thanx again :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement parallel programing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Task[] taskArray = new Task[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++) {
         taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew( (Object obj ) => {
                                                  CustomData data = obj as CustomData;
                                                  if (data == null) 
                                                     return;

                                                  data.ThreadNum = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                                               },
                                               new CustomData() {Name = i, CreationTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks} );
      }
      Task.WaitAll(taskArray);     
      foreach (var task in taskArray) {
         var data = task.AsyncState as CustomData;
         if (data != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} created at {1}, ran on thread #{2}.",
                              data.Name, data.CreationTime, data.ThreadNum);
      }                     
   }
}
```

Comment: that seems interesting, but those MS docs are not very clear on how to implement it in (my) real life scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I think I will have to "duplicate" the `GeneratePDF` method to facilitate the batch processing by implementing the other answers , since I need this method also in non-batch mode...